# Flexbox nav elements overflow on their own in the most weird manner

Tags: html, css, flexbox, media-queries

While testing responsiveness, I encountered the most weird problem. I have these codes for aligning the header as a flexbox and when I resize it over 900px width, the navbar gets out of the header and shows on top of the next element.

**Like this:**

[image]

**This thing happens up until 1205px width and then it gets the way I expect it.**

**Like this:**

[image]

**The anomaly in the first image shouldn't happen because of the media query I have added for Desktop screens.**

**This is the main code for that part:**

**HTML:**

```
<header>
    <a href="#"><img class="logo" src="images/img-tea-cozy-logo.webp" alt="The Tea Cozy Logo"></a>
    <nav>
        <ul class="bar">
            <li><a href="#mission">Mission</a></li>
            <li><a href="#featured">Featured Tea</a></li>
            <li><a href="#locations">Locations</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

**CSS:**

```
/* Header */
header {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 4.54em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid seashell;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: black;
}

header a img {
    height: 2.18em;
    margin-top: 0.45em;
}

nav ul li {
    display: inline-flex;
    text-decoration: underline;
    padding: 0.13em 0.25rem 0 0.25rem;
}

nav ul li a {
    color: seashell;
}
```

**And this is the media query for Desktop:**

```
/* Header for Desktop Screens */
@media only screen and (min-width: 900px) {
    header {
        height: 3.13em;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
    
    header a img {
        height: 2.27em;
        margin: 0.30em 0 0 0.45em;
    }
    
    nav ul li {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0.45em 0.45em;
        font-size: 1em;
    }
}
```

**The weirdest thing happened when I inserted *"and"* after the condition, like this:**

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 900px) and {
...
}
```

**Then it got fixed while it shouldn't have because that's just not the right syntax:**

[image]

**Can anyone help me understand what's happening here and how to fix the problem in the first image?**

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to define `flex-direction: row` for the media query:

```css
/* Header */

header {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 4.54em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid seashell;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: black;
}

header a img {
  height: 2.18em;
  margin-top: 0.45em;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-flex;
  text-decoration: underline;
  padding: 0.13em 0.25rem 0 0.25rem;
}

nav ul li a {
  color: seashell;
}


/* Header for Desktop Screens */

@media only screen and (min-width: 900px) {
  header {
    height: 3.13em;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  header a img {
    height: 2.27em;
    margin: 0.30em 0 0 0.45em;
  }
  nav ul li {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0.45em 0.45em;
    font-size: 1em;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <a href="#"><img class="logo" src="images/img-tea-cozy-logo.webp" alt="The Tea Cozy Logo"></a>
  <nav>
    <ul class="bar">
      <li><a href="#mission">Mission</a></li>
      <li><a href="#featured">Featured Tea</a></li>
      <li><a href="#locations">Locations</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Thanks! This indeed kinda fixed it. The nav elements are no longer piling up on each other but they aren't moving to the right side as intended either. They're just getting away from each other because of space-between and only in 1206px width they move to the right side as expected. Yet your solution did fix the overflowing so thanks again.